# Drawing a partitioned circle with a circle in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

How can I draw a figure of a partitioned circle with a circle in the middle using TikZ or any other LaTeX tool?  [image]

Comment: You probably get more (and better) answers, if you provide a mwe to show what you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version (where the number of spokes can change)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\NumSpokes{6}
  \def\InnerR{1}
  \def\OuterR{3}
  \draw (0,0) circle (\InnerR);
  \draw (0,0) circle (\OuterR);
  \foreach \k in {1,...,\NumSpokes}{%
    \draw (\k*360/\NumSpokes:\InnerR) -- (\k*360/\NumSpokes:\OuterR);}
  \node at (0,0){$\mathrm{Princ}(C)$};
  \node[anchor=south west] at (45:\OuterR){$\mathrm{Div}^0(C)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are of course lots of solutions, one of them shows the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (2cm);
 \foreach \phi in {0,60,120} \draw[line width=0.5pt] (\phi:2cm) -- (\phi+180:2cm);
 \draw[line width=1pt,fill=white] (0,0) node {$Princ(C)$} circle (0.8cm);
 \node[above right] at (45:2.1cm) {$Div^0(C)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would have to modify the text output somehow, but since you want to label it anyway, the option of tikz `nodes` to access any angle on its border could come in handy

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[shape=circle, draw, thick, minimum width=1cm] (inner) at (0, 0) {$Princ(C)$};
    \node[shape=circle, draw, thick, minimum width=3cm] (outer) at (0, 0) {};

    %\draw (inner.0) -- (outer.0);
    %\draw (inner.60) -- (outer.60);
    %...

    \foreach \angle in {0,60,...,300}\draw (inner.\angle) -- (outer.\angle);

    \node[anchor=south west] at (outer.50) {$Div^0(C)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where you can use the `\foreach` for regular sectioning, or the draw commands for arbitrary angles (thanks to [StefanH](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95544/stefanh) in the comments)

With the result:

[image: Circle in a circle. Circleception.]

However, [Jürgen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358755/100384)'s answer also works, so it is probably more a decision of what you intend to do with it.

Comment: You can draw the lines using `\foreach \angle in {0,60,...,300}\draw (inner.\angle) -- (outer.\angle);`

Comment: I tried, but got tons of errors. Are you sure that works for you? Nevermind, I copied your code and it worked. Maybe I had a typo there somewhere and blamed the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,6)
    \bfseries\slshape
    \pscircle[linewidth=3pt]{4.5}%
    \multido{\i=0+60}{6}{\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](1.5; \i)(4.5; \i)}
    \pscircle[linewidth=2.4pt]{1.5}%
    \uput{1em}[r](4.5;60){ Div\textsuperscript{0}(C)}
    \rput(0,0.5){Princ(C)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]